# Find number of elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x] / (x^3 + x^2 + 1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

As part of a longer problem, I need to find the number of elements of the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x] / (x^3 + x^2 + 1)$.

I have no idea where to start with this. I understand that these polynomials have coefficients in the finite field $\mathbb{Z_2}$, so they can take on forms like $x^3 + x^2 + 1$ and $x^3 - x^2 - 1$, but I am not sure where to go from here....

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: I believe you mean $\left|\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^3+x^2+1)\right|$. $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a finite field, with just $0$ and $1$. $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ is the ring of polynomials with coefficients over said field.

Comment: Thanks. Thought I had fixed this. I do indeed mean $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^3+x^2+1)$

Comment: @AnalysisShmalysis The polynomial by which you are factoring is an irreducible cubic (because it has no roots, as you can easily ascertain), hence the quotient will be a field of degree $3$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, hence of $8$ elements. The multiplicative group of a finite field is necessarily cyclic, and it thus follows that the group of units of your quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_7$.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Thank you! Is this because there are two choices for each term in the irreducible polynomial? So 2*2*2?

Comment: @AnalysisShmalysis Not sure what you mean by two choices. In general, if $A$ is a commutative ring and $f \in A[X]$ a monic polynomial of degree $n$, then the quotient $A[X]/(f)$ is a free $A$-module of dimension $n$. Your quotient is thus $3$－dimensional over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ hence isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^3_2$ as a $\mathbb{Z}_2$－vector space.

Comment: Note that since the polynomial is cubic, it's irreducible over $\Bbb Z_2$ if and only if it has no roots in $\Bbb Z_2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you have all the ingredients already, maybe have already put them together to get your desired degree of understanding. But let me lay it all out:

Any time you have a field $k$ and an irreducible $k$-polynomial $f(X)$, then the factor ring $k[X]/\bigl(f(X)\bigr)$ is also a field that contains $k$ in a natural way, via (for $a\in k$) $a\mapsto$ the class of $a$, modulo the ideal $(f)$. So the factor ring can be considered a finite extension of $k$, of degree equal to the degree of $f$.

In your particular case, I’m sure that you’ve seen that $X^3+X^2+1$ is $\Bbb Z_2$-irreducible. The elements of the factor ring can all be written $a+bX+cX^2$ for $a,b,c\in\Bbb Z_2$, since anything of degree three or higher can be made congruent to something of degree $\le2$ by application of Euclidean division.

Thus our extension field is of order eight, and its multiplicative group is of order seven. Since $7$ is a prime, any element of our new field different from $1$ will generate the full group.

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial $x^3+x^2+1$ is irreducible, because neither $0$ nor $1$ is a root $\bmod2$.  So we get a field, an extension of $\Bbb Z_2$.

The dimension of the $\Bbb Z_2$ vector space is $3$, since the possible remainders upon division by $x^3+x^2+1$ are polynomials of degree $2$ or less.

Thus the order of the field is $2^3=8$; its multiplicative group $7$.

Comment: Oh.  I missed that.  So $7$. Thanks @peter a g